# A word for a person who is doubtful and always second-guesses everything he knows

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I was just wondering, I know somebody here knows what word I'm referring to.
For example:

> Person 1: I like that guy because of his looks.
>
> Person 2: Do you really? Or are you just feeling lonely?
>
> Person 1: Geez, you are such a "word".

Comment: Whatever the word is, the person is from Missouri.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The current example sentence suggests that you want a noun. Many of the answers (including the accepted answer) are adjectives, though. Do you care, or is either OK?

Comment: The title is contradictory to the example given. But regardless of that, the selected answer (ambivalent) does not fit either description. First, the word should be a noun to fit in the example sentence, otherwise you need two: e.g. *You're such an ambivalent person* Secondly, [ambivalent](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ambivalent) (simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or feelings) does not mean someone who doesn't believe what they hear, and/or second guesses everything. IMO "a cynic" could fit the example, but not with the title

Comment: @Mari-LouA I see, I agree with everything you said. I also think the best word that describes my example is "cynic". Thank you for all your help and I apologize for the slight difference of my example and my description.

Answer (score 2):

Try [skeptic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skeptic)

A skeptic always doubts and from that I'm sure that he'll second guess pretty much everything, though not exclusively mentioned in the definition.

Comment: If you're looking for a noun(you didn't specify), there's also "doubting thomas" idiom for such a person.

Comment: @Jakub the beauty of sharing: learn something from that experience. Great new addition to my vocabulary.

Comment: That's the word I'm looking for.

Comment: I have to disagree with this... this may well be the word you're groping for, but it doesn't mean what you asked for initially. A sceptic/skeptic does not second-guess things; they merely doubt things and don't take things at face value. I suspect you're crossing from the "doubting Thomas" territory into the land of "know-all"/"smart alec". That's not the same at all.

Comment: @ProfYaffle I see, I suppose you are correct but seeing I've just replied "that's the word I'm looking for" would contradict this statement however I am open for other possible words that fit better with my description. If you do know, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

***wishy-washy***, as defined by [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wishy-washy):

> Irresolute or indecisive: a wishy-washy supervisor who can't   decide
>   what to do.
>
> Lacking in purpose; weak or ineffective: a wishy-washy response to 
>   the criticism

[yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/wishy-washy) has this definition and a good example:

> The definition of wishy washy is someone or something uncertain,
>   indecisive and wavering, or someone who cannot make up his mind.
>
> An example of a wishy washy person is someone who says yes to an
>   invitation, and then no, and then that he will think about it

Comment: Similarly, "Milquetoast" - someone who is overly sensitive, timid, indecisive or cowardly. Based on a cartoon character, Caspar Milquetoast, popular in America in the 1920's.

Answer (score 0):

**Bluffer**

This is another sort of person who makes guesses if he/she  doesn't exactly know the answer.
This person is "doubtful" in a totally different way.

A bluffer is someone who **bluffs**

> Bluff (verb) [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bluff)
>
> Try to deceive someone as to one’s abilities or intentions:
>
> (bluff it out) Survive a difficult situation by maintaining a
>   pretence.

Answer (score 0):

Ambivalent, from Latin ambi- "both" + valentia "strength"

Answer (score 0):

If you want some pedantic equivalent to "skeptic", consider **pyrrhonic** (or "pyrrhonian").

Pyrrho was a Greek philosopher, founder of scepticism. He maintained that true wisdom and happiness lie in suspension of judgment, since certain knowledge is impossible to attain.

Answer (score 0):

A person who has trouble making decisions is ***[indecisive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indecisive)***:

> : not able to make choices quickly and confidently
>
> : not settling something or making something final or certain

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 0):

Reluctant, I believe.

I considered skeptic but a skeptic doesnt necessarily harbor any doubts, they just cannot be sure. Remember that sure and doubting are not polar as they are complementary and that they represent a hindered state towards certainty in either direction. Or something like that.